Unable to change topic's subscription state programmatically in Java - Azure Service Bus
I need to change the state of topic's subscriptions from java code.
Below are the dependencies I added in pom.xml. Spring boot version is 2.5.0 and JDK version is 17. Reason of adding this dependencies is to perform different operations on topics/queue/subscription programmatically. Operations like Create Topic, Create Queue, Create Subscriptions in topic, Delete Topics/Queue/Subscriptions, Create multiple topics with multiple subscriptions, Create subscriptions with filters, Enable/Disable topics and Subscriptions.
**<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.52.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-xml</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.52.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-core-amqp</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-core-http-nety</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.52.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-messaging-servicebus</artifactId>
    <version>7.17.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    <version>12.22.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-common</artifactId>
    <version>12.21.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus-jms</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-servicebus</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-PREVIEW-5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-resourcemanager-servicebus</artifactId>
    <version>2.24.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure.resourcemanager</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-resourcemanager</artifactId>
    <version>2.40.0</version>
</dependency>**

Below is the code and even though i get 200 OK response, status of subscription is not changing from ACTIVE/DISABLED.
Please help.
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.ServiceBusAdministrationClient;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.ServiceBusAdministrationClientBuilder;

public class SubscriptionManager {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String connectionString = "<service-bus-connection-string>";
        String topicName = "<topic-name>";
        String subscriptionName = "<subscription-name>";

        // Create the Service Bus Administration Client
        ServiceBusAdministrationClient adminClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(connectionString)
            .buildClient();

        // Call method to update subscription status
        updateSubscriptionStatus(adminClient, topicName, subscriptionName, true); // true to enable, false to disable
    }

    public static void updateSubscriptionStatus(ServiceBusAdministrationClient client, String topicName, String subscriptionName, boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            client.getSubscription(topicName, subscriptionName)
                .setStatus(com.azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.models.EntityStatus.ACTIVE);
        } else {
            client.getSubscription(topicName, subscriptionName)
                .setStatus(com.azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.models.EntityStatus.DISABLED);
        }
    }
}


Can you provide your GitHub repo?

Hi Dasari. I dont have GitHub repo. I have used the exact code in my java project with connection string and topic name and with subscription name. Even though i get 200 response, in azure portal status of subscription is still active. (Means it is not changing)

Can you share your pom.xml?

@DasariKamali I have updated the question with details. Hope that helps.

I tried the below Spring Boot code to Activate/Deactivate the Azure Service Bus Topic's subscription and successfully did it using POST requests.
Code  :
AzureServiceBusService.java :
package com.example.demoServiceBusDeactivate.service;

import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.ServiceBusAdministrationClient;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.ServiceBusAdministrationClientBuilder;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.models.EntityStatus;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.models.SubscriptionProperties;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AzureServiceBusService {

    @Value("${azure.servicebus.connectionString}")
    private String connectionString;
    private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "kamtopic";
    private static final String SUBSCRIPTION_NAME = "kamsub";

    public void deactivateSubscription() {
        try {
            ServiceBusAdministrationClient adminClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClientBuilder()
                    .connectionString(connectionString)
                    .buildClient();
            SubscriptionProperties subscription = adminClient.getSubscription(TOPIC_NAME, SUBSCRIPTION_NAME);
            subscription.setStatus(EntityStatus.DISABLED);
            adminClient.updateSubscription(subscription);
            System.out.println("Subscription '" + SUBSCRIPTION_NAME + "' is now deactivated.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void activateSubscription() {
        try {
            ServiceBusAdministrationClient adminClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClientBuilder()
                    .connectionString(connectionString)
                    .buildClient();
            SubscriptionProperties subscription = adminClient.getSubscription(TOPIC_NAME, SUBSCRIPTION_NAME);
            subscription.setStatus(EntityStatus.ACTIVE);
            adminClient.updateSubscription(subscription);
            System.out.println("Subscription '" + SUBSCRIPTION_NAME + "' is now activated.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

ServiceBusController.java :
package com.example.demoServiceBusDeactivate.controller;

import com.example.demoServiceBusDeactivate.service.AzureServiceBusService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ServiceBusController {

    @Autowired
    private AzureServiceBusService azureServiceBusService;

    @PostMapping("/deactivate-subscription")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deactivateSubscription() {
        try {
            azureServiceBusService.deactivateSubscription();
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Deactivation initiated.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(500).body("An error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/activate-subscription")
    public ResponseEntity<String> activateSubscription() {
        try {
            azureServiceBusService.activateSubscription();
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Activation initiated.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(500).body("An error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

application.properties :
azure.servicebus.connectionString=<ServiceBusTopicConneString>

pom.xml :
<dependency>  
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>  
    <artifactId>azure-messaging-servicebus</artifactId>  
    <version>7.16.0</version> 
</dependency>

Output :
I send the post request with below URL and Deactived the Azure Service Bus topic's Subscription as shown below.
http://localhost:8080/deactivate-subscription


I saw that the subscription is deactivated in the Azure Service Bus topic, as shown below.

I send the post request with below URL and Actived the Azure Service Bus topic's Subscription as shown below.
http://localhost:8080/activate-subscription


I saw that the subscription is activated in the Azure Service Bus topic, as shown below.

Terminal Output :

